# Google Smarthome local fulfillment - Node code "expressApp.post('/smarthome/delete'" - Firestore delete device from collection

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, webhooks, google-smart-home, fulfillment

I´m trying to allow user to delete an specific device from firestore collection.
Case is the only way to remove a device from home app is deleting it from firestore. I don´t want do delete the entire colletion and do a relink/discovery again.

Within smarthome Node code there is the call:
expressApp.post('/smarthome/delete', (req, res) =>....

This is to delete an specific device, however i don´t know if this call is done from Google home app "remove device" icon inside device settings.

This a second problem, within my home app there is no option, inside device settings, to delete the device, it is missing.  Not sure if is a JSON message problem at device creation discovery phase.

Thank you if can help!